# FireBase realtime database producing value for object

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, registration

i'm creating android app with registration and when user registers, his data is stored on firebase realtime database. So i need every new user is created, 16-long unique number is created speccialy for him. I can do this on the app side, but it seems for me, that it's not what mobile app should do, it's not it's responsibility. Is there a way to configure firebase that way or should i use my own REST app for this purpose?

Comment: Did you consider using Firebase Authentication, which generates a unique ID for each user automatically?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen , yes, but it should be 16 symbols long

Comment: Nothing is built into Firebase Authentication for that, but you could create a custom provider that meets your requirements: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you should be using Firebase Authentication to sign in and generate a UID for your users. Since the default providers all generate UIDs longer than 12 characters (afaik), you could consider [implementing a custom sign-in provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/custom-auth) that generates UIDs that meet your requirements.